# How to prevent an element to drop down?

Tags: css

I have 2 elements in a div, a button and a span:

```
<div class="outer">
    <button>Perform Action</button>
    <span class="option">View Some Stuff</span>
</div>
```

For the span I've applied rules that tell it to make an ellipsis:

```
div.outer {
    width: 50%;
    border: 2px dotted navy;
}

span.option {
    border: 2px solid red;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I've deliberately made the out div 50% width so it's easy to replicate what I am talking about. I've put this code into [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbel/frxdu/). How to make it so that the span will not jump down but instead will form an ellipsis?

Comment: You code in this fiddle doesn't really do anything..

Answer (score 4):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frxdu/1/).

```
span.option {
    border: 2px solid red;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
}
```

You need a set it as `inline-block` or `block`, otherwise a `span` keeps increasing. You may remove or edit the `width` as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

```
button {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
span.option {
  border: 2px solid red;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

span.option has nothing to ellipsis since it has space to grow into. Its container has a width of 50% of the available space.

span.option needs to have a width smaller than the content and it also needs to be a block element

```
div.outer   { border: 2px dotted navy;
              display:inline-block;
              width: 50%;}
span.option { border: 2px solid red;
              text-overflow: ellipsis;
              white-space: nowrap;
          overflow: hidden; 
              display:inline-block;
              width: 70px; }
```